# Bootstrap 3 hidden-* doesn't work on intermediate window sizes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap 3 classes hidden-* seems doesn't work properly on some window sizes. I suppose that this code must hide text forever:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body>
  <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">hidden</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But on some window width (in very narrow intervals) it's shown. Checked in Chrome, Firefox, Edge. Firefox extension "Bootstrap - Responsible Helper" show always "LG" when text is visible.

[Screenshot from Chrome with devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBQbX.png)

[Screenshot from Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxnNo.png)

For reproduction try window size about 767px+- with 100% scale.

What could be the problem?

Comment: For me everything works perfectly in all browsers you listed. The text never becomes visible. Checking the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#responsive-utilities) everything seems to be correct too. Cant reproduce your problem as of right now.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to reproduce the error in a fiddle, but it works fine. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deathstalkersid/07wsmnyr/1/)

Also, if you want to hide something on all sizes, you can use `hidden` instead of `hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg`.

Or if you want to, let's say make it visible at `lg`, use: `hidden visible-lg`. No need for redundant classes for all breakpoints.

Comment: I don't need always hide element, it's only example for a clear demonstration of the "feature"... Real html is more complex.

Comment: Well then that's the demo I suppose? The problem you're having isn't happening in your snippet or Fiddle, so it is something else in your code.

Comment: I can't reproduce on Fiddle, but I see the problem on local html file with this code at all my browsers. I have added one more screenshot from Chrome with devtools shown. 

For reproduction try window size about 767px+- with 100% scale.

Comment: Still works for me, and I did see your screenshot, it's really weird for why it is happening. I'll try on my local as well.

Comment: And I do realize what the problem is. Bootstrap uses a `max-width: 767px;` for `md` with a `min-width: 768px;` for `lg`. So your issue appears when the size is a fraction between 767 and 768. They have fixed this in recent versions, though I don't understand why the issue isn't occurring anywhere else.

Comment: The only solution here is to manually edit the css file to have the media-queries use `min-width` instead of `max-width`, though I am open to a better solution.

Comment: Thanks! Seems it's really a problem with fractional pixels 767-768, 991-992... Although I do not quite understand how a window can has such size at 100% scale.

Comment: This is something I thought and searched about as well, and somehow in my case, everything increments in 1px, whereas in your case that is not happening. Why? I have no idea. But that is why you are facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this table

Also I guess that the problem is in your browser cache or in something else, because if I run the snippet the behaviour is correct

[image]